# Rewrite output of a field and include another one templated

Tags: 7

As a newbie with Drupal 7, I'm wondering if it is possible to rewrite the output of a field, including another field **templated**.

Right now, my rewrite looks like :

```
[field_a] [field_b]
```

And it is displaying field_b as a raw value and not using its template.

Is it possible to display [field_b] using its template ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might excluded the field from display which bypasses the template file that build the display of the field.

So you have to use .tpl file to build the markup you need or put the markup in the rewrite which is not the best solution but may be accepted if you just write simple markup of one tag and classes to let css style apply.